# Postgres simple SQL select query sometimes latency jump to 900ms

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-11, azure-postgres-database

I have an "insert only" table that store user information

- id `bigint` -> Primary key, not null
- user_id `bigint` -> foreign key, not null
- first_name `character varying` null
- middle_name `character varying` null
- last_name `character varying` not null
- email `character varying` not null
- birth_date `date` not null
- phone_number `character varying` not null
- mobile_number `character varying` not null
- street_name `character varying` null

and a user table (insert + update) (most of the times, I don't query this table)

- `id` primary key, not null
- `created_at` date, not null
- `modified_at` date, null

I have an index on `birth_date` column in `user_info` table
and my query looks like this

`SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE birth_date = @p1 and (first_name = @p2 or email = @p3) and (last_name = @p4 or email =@p3);`

Most of the times, the query latency on production environment is `7-26ms` but sometimes, and it's happening frequently actually, the latency jumps up to `900ms` so I see in logs 3-4 queries with latency `180, 200, 700, 900ms` and then goes back to `7-26ms`.

- The table `user_info` is insert-only, so no updates nor deletes
- I am using PostgreSQL 11
- The table `user_info` contains 5 million records, data distribution looks good on production, most of `birth_date(s)` are between 200-1000 records, but only one particular birth date has 110K record (Would this be the issue?)
- server configurations are the default as specified in (Azure Postgres single server)
- Server specs are (4 vCPU, 20 GB memory, Gen 5)
- Maximum concurrent connection to production db is 20 per second
- Best case scenario is only one SQL query executed (the one attached in this question)
- Worst case scenario is First: SQL Query attached in this question, Second: Insert query to `user` table, Third Insert query to `user_info` table
- Another scenario is First: SQL Query attached in this question, Second: Insert query to `user_info` table, Third: update modified time in the `user` table
- querying the `pg_stat_user_tables` trying to understand how many sequential scan vs sequential scan yielded the following result:
  [image]
- executing two queries with `explain analyze` from my local machine using `pgAdmin` against azure postgres server, one with the birth date that contains the most count and one with another birth date, the rest of the values are completely random yieleded the following results

[image]

My problem is:

- I need the latency to not exceed certain threshold

My questions are:

- What the reason behind the latency jump on `user_info` table?
- Would breaking the relationship between the two tables solve the issue? Perhaps when doing updates on `user` table `user_info` table needs to update the foreign key column, because update is actually insert and delete which causes deadrows in the table?
- Is it the data-distribution? And what can I do to improve the latency?

**UPDATED:**

I enabled auto_explain on production, I used a condition to log only queries with latency > 40ms. And ran automated script that queries existing data, 4 of them is with birth date that has 100K row.
And as expected I saw only logs for that particular birth date value:

```
2022-09-19 {TIME REDACTED}-LOG:  duration: 42.421 ms  plan:
    Query Text: 
                    select * from unf.user_info unf
                    where (
                     unf.birth_date = $1
                     and ( unf.first_name = $2 or unf.email = $3 )
                     and ( unf.last_name = $4 or unf.email = $3 ))
    Index Scan using idx_b_date on unf.user_info unf  (cost=0.43..76483.96 rows=1 width=112) (actual time=0.044..42.411 rows=2 loops=1)
      Output: id, user_id, birth_date, first_name, last_name, email,  phone_number, mobile_number, street_name, created_date
      Index Cond: (unf.birth_date = '{REDACTED} 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
      Filter: ((((unf.last_name)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text) OR ((unf.email)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text)) AND (((unf.first_name)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text) OR ((unf.email)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text)))
      Rows Removed by Filter: 119228
      Buffers: shared hit=11025
2022-09-19 {TIME REDACTED}--LOG:  duration: 41.370 ms  plan:
    Query Text: 
                    select * from unf.user_info unf
                    where (
                     unf.birth_date = $1
                     and ( unf.first_name = $2 or unf.email = $3 )
                     and ( unf.last_name = $4 or unf.email = $3 ))
    Index Scan using idx_b_date on unf.user_info unf  (cost=0.43..76483.96 rows=1 width=112) (actual time=0.087..41.359 rows=2 loops=1)
      Output: id, user_id, birth_date, first_name, last_name, email,  phone_number, mobile_number, street_name, created_date
      Index Cond: (unf.birth_date = '{REDACTED} 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
      Filter: ((((unf.last_name)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text) OR ((unf.email)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text)) AND (((unf.first_name)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text) OR ((unf.email)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text)))
      Rows Removed by Filter: 119228
      Buffers: shared hit=11025
2022-09-19 {TIME REDACTED}--LOG:  duration: 41.709 ms  plan:
    Query Text: 
                    select * from unf.user_info unf
                    where (
                     unf.birth_date = $1
                     and ( unf.first_name = $2 or unf.email = $3 )
                     and ( unf.last_name = $4 or unf.email = $3 ))
    Index Scan using idx_b_date on unf.user_info unf  (cost=0.43..76483.96 rows=1 width=112) (actual time=0.079..41.682 rows=2 loops=1)
      Output: id, user_id, birth_date, first_name, last_name, email,  phone_number, mobile_number, street_name, created_date
      Index Cond: (unf.birth_date = '{REDACTED} 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
      Filter: ((((unf.last_name)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text) OR ((unf.email)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text)) AND (((unf.first_name)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text) OR ((unf.email)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text)))
      Rows Removed by Filter: 119228
      Buffers: shared hit=11025
2022-09-19 {TIME REDACTED}--LOG:  duration: 40.581 ms  plan:
    Query Text: 
                    select * from unf.user_info unf
                    where (
                     unf.birth_date = $1
                     and ( unf.first_name = $2 or unf.email = $3 )
                     and ( unf.last_name = $4 or unf.email = $3 ))
    Index Scan using idx_b_date on unf.user_info unf  (cost=0.43..76483.96 rows=1 width=112) (actual time=0.057..40.568 rows=2 loops=1)
      Output: id, user_id, birth_date, first_name, last_name, email,  phone_number, mobile_number, street_name, created_date
      Index Cond: (unf.birth_date = '{REDACTED} 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
      Filter: ((((unf.last_name)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text) OR ((unf.email)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text)) AND (((unf.first_name)::text = 'n'::text) OR ((unf.email)::text = '{REDACTED}'::text)))
      Rows Removed by Filter: 119228
      Buffers: shared hit=11025
```

Comment: Whose logs?  How is the logging configured?  Is there anything other than just the latency in the log files?  Are the slow ones associated with particular set of parameters?Can you set up auto_explain to record slow queries, along with the BUFFERS and ANALYZE?

Comment: @jjanes thanks for your comment! I updated my question and added more info. The logs are from Azure Telemtry, it calculate the time once the web application send the query to azure server. I think it's pretty much accurate. But definitely good point, I'll try to enable `auto_explain` in a non-peak time or perhaps couple hours during the peak time. I am a bit concerned about the overhead of logs on the query performance.

Comment: In the slow query, there were way more rows found by the index scan that do not match the filter condition.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I actually redacted the birth date values, in the slow query as I mentioned in the question the birth date value has 100K rows with that birth_date value, but other bith_date values has records count between 200-1000.

Comment: Well, there you have your explanation.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe You mean the data distribution of the index on production? Is there anything that can be done here? production environment is very performance sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your slow query, there are 1970 rows with `birth_date = 'REDACTED'`, while in the slow query, there are 124287. So it is only natural that the index scan takes longer.

Since you put an `OR` into your `WHERE` condition (which makes indexing harder), the only simple improvement I can think of is to add the filter columns to the index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON user_info (birth_date, first_name, email);
```

Perhaps you can rewrite the query to avoid the `OR`, then more is possible.

Comment: The issue is, only birth date, last name and email are non-nullable, as I mentioned in the question, first_name is a nullable field :)

Comment: That confirms that my answer must go in the right direction. I don't see how nullability has an influence on this.

Answer (score 2):

The query's index condition is unnecessary complex:

```
-- version 1, original
WHERE birth_date = @p1 
  AND ( first_name = @p2 OR email = @p3 )
  AND ( last_name = @p4 OR email = @p3 )
```

It is equivalent to:

```
-- version 2
WHERE birth_date = @p1 
  AND (  first_name = @p2 AND last_name = @p4
      OR email = @p3
      )
```

and to this (parentheses redundant, only shown for clarity):

```
-- version 3
WHERE ( birth_date = @p1 AND first_name = @p2 AND last_name = @p4 )
   OR ( birth_date = @p1 AND email = @p3 )
```

The 3rd variation above makes it easier to identify better index candidates, both for humans and Postgres' planner. The planner has some capabilities of rewriting/simplifying boolean conditions but it can't identify every possible simplification.

Therefore, I suggest you add both these indexes:

```
INDEX (birth_date, first_name, last_name)
INDEX (birth_date, email)
```

and check both the 3rd option above and the rewriting using `UNION`:

```
-- version 3
SELECT * 
FROM user_info 
WHERE birth_date = @p1 AND first_name = @p2 AND last_name = @p4
   OR birth_date = @p1 AND email = @p ;

-- version 4: UNION
SELECT * 
FROM user_info 
WHERE birth_date = @p1 AND first_name = @p2 AND last_name = @p4
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM user_info 
WHERE birth_date = @p1 AND email = @p3  ;
```